# Seeking shorter way of writing this simple code in Python

Tags: python

Is there a shorter, more neatly looking way of writing this code:

```
k = 0
        
if row.is_completed == True:
    k += 1
if row.is_signed == True:
    k += 1
if row.is_paid == True:
    k += 1
```

I need to check what number of these statements are true, hence why I'm incrementing a var and then checking its number later in the code.
I've tried writing something like `k += 1 if row.is_completed else k`, for each of these statements but it's not working correctly for some reason.

Comment: For sure you don't need things like `== True`... This is more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If each of your `row.is_*` attributes is either True or False, you can write `k = row.is_completed + row.is_signed + row.is_paid`.

Comment: @Idos You're right, I didn't practice in a while and got a little sloppy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k = row.is_completed + row.is_signed + row.is_paid
```

Comment: or with `sum`:   `k = sum((row.is_completed, row.is_signed, row.is_paid))`

Answer (score 1):

I'd think twice before shortening it. Sometimes shorter can be harder to read.
The most assumption-resistant equivalent I can come up with is

Untested:

```
sum([1 for x in [
    row.is_signed,
    row.is_completed,
    row.is_paid,
] if x == True])
```

Question: What should the result be if one or more of the properties is:

- 42
- "cheese"
- []
- [0]
- "False"

Tbh once the possibility of different types of data are taken into consideration, I'd stick with your original solution.
If you wanted to make it more scalable, I'd probably stick with a simple for loop. This is probably actually longer than your example, but additions can be made very easily.

Once again untested:

```
props = [
    row.is_signed,
    row.is_completed,
    row.is_paid,
]
k = 0
for prop in props:
    if prop == True:
        k += 1
```

Comment: You're right, but the values are added from a table, can be either True or False. As for scalability, I don't think I'll add more colums in the table that need this. But your second solution is pretty good and thank you for explaining.

Comment: If you've validated that the values you've read from the database are indeed Boolean (either True or False) or if you've cast them to boolean, then you can (and in my opinion should) shorten the "if prop == True:" to "if prop:".